# Is Android persistent user data available after an app update?

Tags: android

I'm sure it's a dumb question. But still. User activity is saved to storage (Internal/External) and `SharedPreferences`. Will it be available after update of the app?

Thanks for answers!

Comment: By default, user data in internal storage (shared preference , ... ) will not change after application update but if you delete app, user data in internal storage will be deleted.

Comment: Note that internal storage in android programming means the storage that the user can't access directly, like shared preference. so internal SD card and external SD cards are both external storage.

Comment: Thank you, it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to SO!

On an update all app data remains. That's for updates that you install manually with adb or updates that get rolled out from PlayStore. This also means that if you have changes in your data model from one version to the next you'll have to make sure the new version can handle the old data.

If the app get uninstalled and reinstalled the data is usually lost but there are some instances where the OS can create backups of app data and it reappears even when an app gets uninstalled and reinstalled. See [allowBackup](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element#allowbackup) for this.